# Implementar ReCaptcha V3 en Nextjs

Tags: next.js, recaptcha

Como implementar correctamente Recaptcha v3 en next.
tengo una pagina web y debo implementar recaptcha en un único componente, el tema es si solo debo envolver el componente al que le aplico la validación de recaptcha o es a todo el proyecto, estoy usando react-google-recaptcha-v3 npm
esto es parte de mi código envolviendo únicamente al componente al que le quiero aplicar recaptcha.

La duda resulta por que todas las peticiones que e recibido me devuelven un puntaje de 0.9

```
import {WithGoogleRecaptchaExample} from "../../views/PagoConTarjeta/xxxxxx";
import {
  GoogleReCaptchaProvider,
  withGoogleReCaptcha
} from 'react-google-recaptcha-v3';
import Api from "../../Services/Api";

const { KEY_V3_CAPTCHA } = Api

export default function Index(props) {
  
  return (
    <Layout title={`Pago con Tarjeta | ${process.env.NAME_PAGE} - ${process.env.URL_PAGE}`}>
      <GoogleReCaptchaProvider reCaptchaKey={KEY_V3_CAPTCHA}>
      <WithGoogleRecaptchaExample {...props}/>

      </GoogleReCaptchaProvider>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```